# YII 1 how to use multiple database in one application and one single login

Tags: authentication, yii, multiple-databases

YII 1.

I have multiple database 
ex: db_company_a and db_company_b with same structure and table
and in every database have tbl_user and in tbl_user have company_id.
my question how to use single page login and redirect based on user login?

i have follow this but doesnt work  [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/544/multiple-database-connection-select-database-based-on-login-user-id-dynamic)!

Comment: Have created component? Have extend you user model to this component? Have added getDbConnection function in your user model? check all these things once.

Comment: For more information you can follow this article. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/123/multiple-database-support-in-yii/

Comment: thanks @IrfanAli i have solved my problem, im forget with tablePrefix.
and i solved the login with create view in new database and redirect based on user_database